# How to get VirtualBox web server to use a public domain name?

Tags: centos, virtualbox, ip, hostname, domain

Here's the situation:

1. CentOS 7 x64 latest is installed in VirtualBox on my PC.
2. Webmin is installed and port forwarded through VirtualBox so I can access the Webmin interface on the host PC. So the server is working.
3. I've configured my domain registrar to make glue records pointing to my home IP (e.g. `ns1.mydomain.com` > , `ns2.mydomain.com` > )
4. I setup my DNS master zone files inside Webmin, using the same format of zone file found on my live server which is working fine and hosting its own nameservers.

What I want to do is go to `mydomain.com` and access my domain which is hosted on my home server inside VirtualBox.

Presently I tested and even though BIND seems to be valid,

How do I set up CentOS so that it works for a live domain?

Comment: How is virtualbox’s network set up on your PC?  Bridged? Forwarded ports?

Comment: I have forwarded ports over NAT. I also tried bridged. What's the right way?